# Docker Swarm on AWS: Expose service port not working on AWS virtual machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm

I have 2 AWS virtual machines instances, running on 2 IPv4 public IPs A.B.C.D and X.Y.Z.W
I installed Docker on both machines, and launch Docker Swarm with node A.B.C.D as manager and X.Y.Z.W as worker. When I launched Docker Swarm, I used the A.B.C.D as the advertise-addr, like so:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr A.B.C.D
```

The Swarm initialized successfully

The problem occurred when I created a service from the image [jwilder/whoami](https://github.com/jwilder/whoami) and exposed the service on port 8000:

```
docker service create -d -p 8000:8000 jwilder/whoami
```

I expected that I can access the service on port 8000 from both nodes, according to the Swarm Routing Mesh documentation. However, in fact I can only access the service from only one node, which is the node that the container was running on

I also tried this experiment on Azure virtual machine and alo failed, so I guess this is a problem with Swarm on these cloud providers, maybe some networking misconfiguration.

Does anyone know how to fix this ? Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

One main problem that you are not refer is about the Security Groups. You expose port 8000 but by default, the Security Groups only open port 22 for SSH. Please check the SG and make sure you open the necessary ports.

Comment: Yes I opened all the ports on the Inbound rules

Comment: So there is 3 additional port in the SG? 8000, 7946 and 4789. Try to ping between or traceroute for troubleshooting